# Why it shows Request failed with status code 401?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtserverinit

I am getting data in Nuxt server init with axios, Request failed with status code 401, and createError

````
        await $axios
            .get("/shopping/get-wishlist")
            .then(response => {
                commit('setWishlist', response.data.payload.wishlist)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        await $axios
            .get("/shopping/get-cart")
            .then(response => {
                commit('setBasketList', response.data.payload.cart.items)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }, ```

```at createError (node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)```
````